# select latest 20 records under each category from one table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
    Id  ||  title  ||  source  ||.. || category
------------------------------------------
    1   ||  John   ||  abs.com ||.. || a
    3   ||  Tala   ||  nar.com ||.. || a
    4   ||  John   ||  kam.com ||.. || b
```

I want to make a query or stored procedure to get latest 20 records from each category. anyone can help me here ?

Comment: Try yourself with `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @Bharadwaj I know what's ROW_NUMBER(), but how could it help me here ?

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737373/sql-select-top-3-values-per-group-with-condition

Comment: how would you determine what is the latest record? Id column, datetime stamp? Nothing to go by from your code sample...

Comment: @MilenPavlov sorry, i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select rn, Id, title, [source], category
From 
(   select Id, title, [source], category, ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By Category order by Id desc) as rn
    from yourTable
) a  where rn <= 20
order by category, rn
```

The idea is to create unique sequence numbers(using `Row_Number()`) for each category (`Partition By Category`) starting from the highest id for each category (`..order by Id desc`). Ultimately this splits the data on categories and assigns the lowest number (starting from one) to the category having the highest id (most recent entry) and this is happening for all category groups.

Comment: it works well, but can you explain your query please ?